# Save a pandas DataFrame in a group of h5py for later use

Tags: pandas, h5py

I want to append a pandas `DataFrame` object to an existing `h5py` file, whether as a subgroup or dataset, with all the index and header information. Is that possible? I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import h5py
f = h5py.File('f.h5', 'r+')
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=['X', 'Y'])
f['df'] = df
```

From another script, I would like to access `f.h5`, but the output of `f['df'][()]` is `array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]])`, which doesn't contain the header information.

Answer (score 2):

You can write to an existing hdf5 file directly with Pandas via [`pd.DataFrame.to_hdf()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html) and read it back in with [`pd.read_hdf()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_hdf.html). You just have to make sure to read and write with the same key.

To write to the h5 file:

```
existing_hdf5 = "f.h5"
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], 
                  columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=['X', 'Y'])

df.to_hdf(existing_hdf5 , key='df')
```

Then you can read by:

```
df2 = pd.read_hdf(existing_hdf5 , key='df')
print(df2)

   A  B  C
X  1  2  3
Y  4  5  6
```

Note that you can also make the dataframe appendable using `format="table"` which requires the option dependency of `Pytables`